# How to configure db-reverse-engineer plugin

Tags: grails, configuration, groovy, grails-plugin

I am a total Grails noob trying to configure the db-reverse-engineer plugin for my first project.  [Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/single.html#2%20Configuration) for the plugin indicates that I need to configure it, but I don't see where I am supposed to edit configuration.

Is there a configuration file in my project I need to edit?  I have searched through the ./grails-app/conf folder for grails.plugin (the prefix for this plugin's configuration) and found nothing.  An SO or Google search for how to configure grails plugins also returns void.  I know this is a lame question, but how do I configure this plugin?  Is there a UI I need to use, or are there files somewhere to edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure your database in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`.  In particular, you'll need to provide the JDBC URL, the database dialect and the databases's username and password.

You'll also have to add some extra `db-reverse-engineer` configuration to `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`.  This file will already exist.  Just append the new properties at the end.

Finally, run the reverse engineer script to generate your domain classes:

```
grails db-reverse-engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

The right place for that would be the file `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`.

Just add what you need at the bottom.